# VBA disable Checkbox click event from firing inside Textbox change event

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I want to do something like this. Don't know if it is possible in Excel VBA. On a user form, I have a checkbox and a text box.

When I check the checkbox, the checkbox's caption will be inserted into the text box, when I uncheck the checkbox, the checkbox's caption will be removed from the same text box.

When i write into the text box the caption of the checkbox, inside the text box change event, the checkbox status will be updated. And at the same moment, the checkbox click event is fired and the caption text will be doubled. How can I stop the checkbox click event from firing twice?

Checkbox's click event code:

```
Private Sub cbSelect_Click()
    With TextBox1
        .Value = IIf(cbSelect.Value, _
        .Value & cbSelect.Caption, _
        Replace(.Value, cbSelect.Caption, vbNullString))
    End With
End Sub
```

Text box's change event code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If InStr(TextBox1.Value, cbSelect.Caption) Then
        cbSelect.Value = 1
    Else
        cbSelect.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Any idea?

Comment: have you tested any of the answers you got? any feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code, the checkbox status did not change which I believe is due to the use of binary values (`1` / `0`) instead of Boolean (`True` / `False`)

I changed your `Textbox1_Change`code to the following and as soon as I delete part of the checkbox c

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If InStr(TextBox1.Value, cbSelect.Caption) Then
        cbSelect.Value = True
    Else
        cbSelect.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `Public TextBoxFlag As Boolean` at the `User_Form` module level, and this "flag" is being modifed and checked in both Control's events.

Once the code enters the `TextBox1_Change` event the flag gets a `True` value, and when the code reaches the `cbSelect_Click` event, it doesn't run the code inside if the value of `TextBoxFlag = True`, only if it's `False` (didn't came from the `TextBox1_Change` event, but directly from the `CheckBox1` event).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public TextBoxFlag As Boolean

Private Sub cbSelect_Click()

    ' check if event came from the value being modified in the TextBox1_Change event
    If TextBoxFlag = False Then
        With TextBox1
            .Value = IIf(cbSelect.Value, _
            .Value & cbSelect.Caption, _
            Replace(.Value, cbSelect.Caption, vbNullString))
        End With
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    ' raise the flag >> came from TextBox change event
    TextBoxFlag = True

    If InStr(TextBox1.Value, cbSelect.Caption) > 0 Then
        cbSelect.Value = True
    Else
        cbSelect.Value = False
    End If
    ' reset the flag
    TextBoxFlag = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

your code actually worked for me without the issue you described just substituting:

```
InStr(Me.TextBox1.Value, Me.cbSelect.Caption)
```

with :

```
InStr(Me.TextBox1.Value, Me.cbSelect.Caption) > 0
```

BTW here's some possibly useful coding advices :

- I'd always use `Me` keyword and refer to `Userform` controls.

  this will also have `Intellisense` help you in finding `UserForm` controls names
- your `cbSelect.Value` setting code can be shortened to one line

as a result of all what above:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.cbSelect= InStr(Me.TextBox1.Value, Me.cbSelect.Caption) > 0
End Sub

Private Sub cbSelect_Click()
    With Me.TextBox1
        .Value = IIf(Me.cbSelect, _
                    .Value & Me.cbSelect.Caption, _
                    Replace(.Value, Me.cbSelect.Caption, vbNullString))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ĐứcThanhNguyễn, did you get through it?

Comment: @ĐứcThanhNguyễn, It'd be nice of you giving proper feedback to people trying at helping you. Thank you